# Why is location.reload() displaying the jQuery.js file in the uiwebview instead of the html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, uiwebview

I am running this code when I click a certain button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ScoreNonClickedWordsButton").click(function () {
       $(this).parent().find("a.scoreThisWord").each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         this.click();
       });
   $("a.scoreThisWord").removeClass("scoreThisWord");
   location.reload(true);
   });
});
```

I want the page to reload at the end of the function. Instead of reloading the html it is displaying the contents of the jQuery.js file. Why is this happening?

Comment: So what's the use of invoking clicks on anchors and removing classes, only to reload the page ?

Comment: The links are myApp://?q=foo links because this is how I am passing data to swift from javascript.

Comment: The code as posted seems to be missing a `})` somewhere.

Comment: Did your console show any errors?

Comment: @Pointy Thanks. There is more code after that so I forgot to include them. I edit the question to include them.

Comment: @che-azeh I am not sure how to view the console when I am running this in a virtual iOS device.